# Как сделать функцию, которая при нажатии на любую кнопку оставит её `нажатой`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, pyqt, qpushbutton

У меня есть много кнопок и нужно чтобы при нажатии на любую из них эта кнопка оставалась `"нажатой"`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Представим, что это поле для игры крестики нолики, 
после каждого нажатия там должен например смениться цвет и кнопка должна остаться вжатой, типа как пупырчатая пленка.

Не знаю как написать соответствующую функцию, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Sulek Levrone, пожалуйста, покажите что вы уже написали и лучше расскажите что в итоге вы хотите получить.

Comment: ну представим что это поле для игры крестики нолики, после каждого нажатия там должен например смениться цвет и кнопка должна остаться вжатой, типа как пупырчатая пленка.

Comment: при нажатии просто меняй изображение, которое рисует кнопку

Comment: @Эникейщик  при нажатии кнопка должна оставаться "нажатой", т.е. ее нельзя нажать еще раз.

Comment: @S.Nick если при последующих нажатиях менять на то же самое изображение, то и получится, что нельзя нажать еще раз

Comment: Возможно, стоит ввести такое понятие как "state"  с двумя значениями (up, down) и по клику их менять. Если state=down, то state изменить уже нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, ВСЕГДА предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему или код, который вы уже написали!!!

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(50, 50)        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: green;")        
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        many_buttons = 100                       # хотим создать 100 кнопок
        column = 10                              # 10 столбцов
        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.buttons = []
        
        for step in range(many_buttons):
            btn = PushButton()   
            row = step // column
            col = step % column
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, b=btn, r=row, c=col: 
                self.onClicked(b, [r, c]))        
            layout.addWidget(btn, row, col)  
            self.buttons.append(btn)
        
        self.button_clean_up = QPushButton('Restart')
        self.button_clean_up.clicked.connect(self.clean_up)
        self.button_clean_up.setStyleSheet("color: #AF460F; font-size: 26px;")
        layout.addWidget(self.button_clean_up, 12, 6, 1, 3) 

    def onClicked(self, btn, cord):
        btn.setStyleSheet("")
        btn.setDisabled(True)

    def clean_up(self):
        for b in self.buttons:
            b.setText("")
            b.setDisabled(False)
            b.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: green;")
         

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setFixedSize(575, 620)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @SulekLevrone что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Добавь переменную bool is_toggled. При нажатии на кнопку, is_toggle меняешь на true. Если нажимаешь ещё раз, то false. А далее ставишь условие, если is_toggle == true, то кнопка нажата. Если false, соответственно нет